# Filter members and auto-cast in Visual Studio (Eclipse like)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, eclipse

I've been switching back and forth between Visual Studio and Eclipse and I got used to couple things in Eclipse:

1. CTRL+1 to autocast variable
2. CTRL+o to filter memebers in class and autojump
3. CTRL+3 to get list of all commands

Do you guys have any suggestion how I could get similar functionality in Visual Studio? Any add-in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/